# SQL-query order by multiple columns having null values

Tags: sql, null, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I got a table like this (Note: the real table has by far more columns):

```
street|zip
-----------
'b'   |0
'a'   |0
'c'   |null
'f'   |1
null  |0
null  |null
```

I would like to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY street, zip
```

The result of this query would be this:

```
street|zip
-----------
'a'   |0
'b'   |0
'c'   |null
'f'   |1
null  |0
null  |null
```

Now the question is how must the query look like to produce this output (is it even possible?):

```
street|zip
-----------
'a'   |0
'b'   |0
'c'   |null
null  |0
'f'   |1
null  |null
```

If the value of a column is null it should be ignored/interpreted as a wildecard.
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not look possible. You can't build a reproducible rule for that.

Your first example would also be valid if you treated null as a wild card.

```
street|zip
-----------
'a'   |0
'b'   |0
'c'   |null
null  |0
null  |null
'f'   |1
```

would be too.